# api-platform: Limit the records a user can see based on access logic

Tags: symfony, security, event-listener, api-platform.com

I would like to use Symfonys API platform for a BI application. I know it is great in security and flexibility, but I need something I have not yet found in documentation or here on stackoverflow.

I have multiple databases and each db contains data of multiple customers.

Now I want to limit which customers a logged in BI user can see. If a BI user is limited to see only data of a subset of customers (that relation is present in the DB), how can I make sure this user will only see data related to those customers, and not any other?

I could use a customer ID as entrypoint, would since it should contain data of *all* customers and the list of customers is dynamic, this will not work.

I know there must be a way to have that security on kernel level/Event Listener but was unable to find this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: try [Voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) in the service that gathers the customers, and filter the initial resultset, or modify the query

Comment: Thanks @zeding I will have a look into that!